# group extension with finite abelian group

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, finite-groups

I am a student majoring physics. The question below may be simple but confuse me. Thanks for any suggestion or detailed answer.

Given two finite abelian group $N$ and $A$, the question is how many possible $G$(including abelian and nonabelian $G$) satisfying the following short exact sequence:

$0 \rightarrow N \rightarrow G \rightarrow A \rightarrow 0$.

In another words(to my understanding), how many possible choices of $G$ which are group extension of $N$ by $A$? I am grateful who can give me the detailed consideration of the case: $N=Z_{n_1}\times Z_{n_2}$, and $A=Z_{m_1} \times Z_{m_2}$.

Comment: This is not a trivial question, even when adding conditions (such as requiring that $N$ lie in the center; then you are talking about the second cohomology group)

Comment: "How many possible $G$" is ambiguous. How many up to what? Isomorphim class of $G$? Isomorphism classes of extensions?

Comment: Classification, up to group isomorphism, of finite metacylic groups ($N \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{n_1}$ and $A \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{n_2}$) has a long history, see C. Hempel's "Metacyclic Groups" in Communications in Algebra, 2000.

Comment: @YCor Sorry for the ambiguity. Actually I consider the isomorphism class of G.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for pointing out this. Can you give some more details or some relative references.

Comment: @LucGuyot Thanks for you reference.

Comment: There are many references for the second cohomology group and how it relates to the number of equivalent central extensions; I learned it from Rotman's "Introduction to the Theory of Groups" (4th Edition). Ken Brown's "Cohomology of Groups" would also include it. 

I don't think you'll get an easy formula even for your simpler situation. Like I said, this is not a trivial problem, and even then, counting the number of equivalent extensions overcounts the number of isomorphic groups.